# What happens to a Windows Dynamic Drive

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, dynamic-disk

In my windows (Windows 7) I have two primary logical volumns, One is on a SSD harddrive for my operating system and installed software, and my other is a Dynamic volume for my stored media. (I do alot of work with HD footage) I have all my media on the original DV tapes for backup purposes, just having them all available on my harddrive at all times is a major convience for me, well worth the few hundred dollar investment those 2TB drives were.

Anyway, Long story short is my windows install has become problematic and I want to reformat windows.   Does this, or will this effect my dynamic drive in any way?  I've got almost 3 TB of video on there and i really dont want to re-import all my DV tapes.

[image]

Comment: I believe the dynamic volume may not be recognised on a new install of Windows, but I am not sure of this, so I'm not going to commit to a real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of things, you've extended Drive E so that it's about 4 TB in size.  The ONLY way you can do this without a RAID controller is to use the technologies Windows makes available to extend the data across multiple drives.  (I get concerned about disk failure which would call ALL data on the E: drive to be inaccessible and may involve costly data recovery so I don't do this - I'd rather have 3 separate drives OR mount them under one folder). But I digress.

If you reinstall Windows, the disk should appear as foreign and all that should be necessary is to right click on it and select "Import..." (or some VERY similar wording).

Comment: yea, i'm considering dropping in a 3rd 2TD drive and Raid5'ing the entire thing, Was really more of specific answer as to how the windows install process treats those drives.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the storage drives when you reinstall the OS. When the reinstall is done and all updated, shut down and connect the drives back